# Customize Modern SharePoint listform

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, modern-experience, powerapp

Currently i am working on modern SharePoint and i have one requirement to create purchase order form.

To create Purchase order form, i have 2 list. One is for vendor and other detail and another list is for purchase items.

Below are the lists

[image]

Second list has lookup of First list.

Now my form should look like below

[image]

can please anybody help me how should i implement it **Modern List**?

I had tried to create it in **PowerApp** but how should i add second list detail in first list form and save data to second list?

Is there any other way we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use multiple Gallery controls as repeating sections to meet the  requirement. kindly check the videos by shane young

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgznk4XlPCo (PowerApps Repeating Tables like InfoPath Part 1 - Enter the data)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DylxsXIUyDc (PowerApps Repeating Tables like InfoPath Part 2 - View and edit the Data)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUX_0AA4-Hs (PowerApps Repeating Tables Like InfoPath Part 3 - Inline editing)

Hope this helps

Comment: yes and how can i save data to 2 lists?? @Tarun